# Customize StyleCop by adding StyleCop.json

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

I want to customize *StyleCop* rules, for example, by default *StyleCop* requires all using directives to be added inside the namespace:

[image]

In my project, I have disabled this rule... now I want to to modify this rule (or add a new rule) which would require:

**all using directives should be defined outside of namespaces**

I have seen [this document](https://blog.submain.com/stylecop-detailed-guide/), which explains this customization can be done by adding *StyleCop.json*:

> The easiest way to add the file is to open a file that violates rule
>   SA1633. This is the rule that requires a file header (e.g., a
>   copyright notice). Press “CTRL + .” and you’ll see an option to add
>   the file:

And then this can be added to *StyleCop.json*:

```
"orderingRules": {
    "usingDirectivesPlacement": "outsideNamespace"
}
```

"CTRL + ." does not open any quick action for me, and I am not clear how/where I should add *StyleCop.Json* to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had installed, StyleCop using [StyleCop Installer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop).

[This document](https://blog.submain.com/stylecop-detailed-guide/) is expecting that StyleCop is installed using [StyleCop.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/stylecop.analyzers/) Nuget package.

I am not sure how to Customize StyleCop, when installed using StyleCop Installer, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StyleCop), StyleCop.Analyzers is the best option, from VS 2015 and going forward.